# Cannot load config files when running the program from another program

Tags: c#, file, process

I created a `WinFrom` app and the release `.exe` is located in certain directory, let say,

```
C:\App\bin\Release\WinFormApp.exe
```

In the application directory, I have some config files written in the `XML` format and stored in the directory's `Config` subfolder:

```
C:\App\bin\Release\Config\MyConfig1.xml
C:\App\bin\Release\Config\MyConfig2.xml
C:\App\bin\Release\Config\MyConfig3.xml
```

Then I have a `private field` in the application's `.cs` file storing the default sub-directory name where the config files are located:

```
private string configFoldername = "Config";
```

Thus, when the application is run, it will first load the config files by using `FileStream` and `XMLSerializer` as follow:

```
filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(configFoldername, "MyConfig1.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyAppConfig1));

//... some others

filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(configFoldername, "MyConfig2.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyAppConfig2));

//... some others

filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(configFoldername, "MyConfig3.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyAppConfig3));

//... some others
```

So far so good. The application run without issue. But then I create a simple `watcher` program for my app to check if it is running well and if it is not, then the watcher will restart the program. The relevant part in my `watcher` program is shown as follow:

```
//In the Watcher program
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\App\bin\Release\WinFormApp.exe";          
process.Start();
```

I was surprised when I found out that my application cannot load the config files this time. The serializer fails, showing that the files do not exist. But if I run the program not from the watcher, but directly running the application, there is no issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `FileStream` call:

```
filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(configFoldername, "MyConfig1.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

The path given is using relative path by only giving the `configFoldername` instead of the full path.

Thus, *surprisingly*, when the `WinForm` program is run from another program (the `Watcher`) the `FileStream` default path will be the `Watcher`'s app path instead of the `WinForm`'s app path and making the `FileStream` unable to get the file from the right folder.

To solve it, I use the absolute path instead of the relative path. In the initialization of the `WinForm` app, I use `Application.StartupPath` to get the absolute path of the `WinForm` application.

```
private string configFoldername = "Config";
private string configFolderpath; //declare new variable here

...and in the initialization

string root = Application.StartupPath;
configFolderpath = Path.Combine(root, configFoldername); //making this having the absolute path.
```

Then the new deserialization looks like this:

```
filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(configFolderpath, "MyConfig1.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyAppConfig1));

//... some others

filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(configFolderpath, "MyConfig2.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyAppConfig2));

//... some others

filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(configFolderpath, "MyConfig3.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyAppConfig3));

//... some others
```

And now it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
private string configFoldername = "Config";
```

With:

```
private string configFoldername = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Config");
```

Or set the `process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory`:

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\App\bin\Release\";
```

Comment: Ah yes, the problem is with the path as I figure it out. Thanks for the answer, though. Upvoted. It becomes especially problematic because the watcher program does not really have variable info on the actual `StartUpPath` Thus, the change was made in the `WinForm` app.